# Top Navbar that moves to the side when dekstop res? (Bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive

I've been trying to make a responsive Nav-bar that is on top when Mobile and on side when Desktop.

The problem is that to achieve this I'm not sure what is the correct approach regarding the Rows and cols. Because on `mobiles`, I have a Row with `col-x-12` for top-nav and another Row with `col-x-12` for the content below.

But if i want to achieve a side by side cols (`col-2 and col-10`) for dekstop sizes, I have a problem regarding the 2 rows. They can't be side by side.
Also I tried to make 1 row and 2 cols, for navbar (`col-md-12 col-lg-2`).

For content (`col-md-12 col-lg-10`), but i don't know if its safe to have 2 `cols-12` inside one single row, So, what would be the correct approach for this responsive `navbar`? thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 0):

I may have a solution for you.

Try to make two div, one is only displayed in desktop resolution (it would contain the sidebar), and one is displayed in mobile resolution (would contain the topbar)

```
<div class="d-lg-none">hide on screens wider than lg</div>
<div class="d-none d-lg-block">hide on screens smaller than lg</div>
```

Take a look at that https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/display/